# Error while creating app using create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I installed yarn, updated node, npm and yarn as well, cleared cache and still facing the same errors.

**Command used:**

```
create-react-app confusion --scripts-version=react-scripts@1.1.4
```

**Errors are as follows:**

```
Creating a new React app in /home/nandini/Documents/courseraFSWD/React/confusion.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

➤ YN0000: ┌ Resolution step
➤ YN0061: │ extract-text-webpack-plugin@npm:3.0.2 is deprecated: Deprecated. Please use https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin
➤ YN0061: │ fsevents@npm:1.2.13 is deprecated: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
➤ YN0061: │ fsevents@npm:1.2.13 is deprecated: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
➤ YN0061: │ browserslist@npm:2.11.3 is deprecated: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
➤ YN0061: │ core-js@npm:2.6.11 is deprecated: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
➤ YN0061: │ sw-precache@npm:5.2.1 is deprecated: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
➤ YN0061: │ chokidar@npm:1.7.0 is deprecated: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
➤ YN0032: │ nan@npm:2.14.1: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ sw-toolbox@npm:3.6.0 is deprecated: Please migrate to Workbox: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/migrations/migrate-from-sw
➤ YN0061: │ chokidar@npm:2.1.8 is deprecated: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
➤ YN0061: │ request@npm:2.88.2 is deprecated: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
➤ YN0061: │ browserslist@npm:1.7.7 is deprecated: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
➤ YN0061: │ browserslist@npm:1.7.7 is deprecated: Browserslist 2 could fail on reading Browserslist >3.0 config used in other tools.
➤ YN0061: │ circular-json@npm:0.3.3 is deprecated: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.1.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ fsevents@npm:2.1.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0032: │ evp_bytestokey@npm:1.0.3: Implicit dependencies on node-gyp are discouraged
➤ YN0061: │ har-validator@npm:5.1.5 is deprecated: this library is no longer supported
➤ YN0061: │ resolve-url@npm:0.2.1 is deprecated: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
➤ YN0061: │ urix@npm:0.1.0 is deprecated: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 46.94s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
➤ YN0013: │ yargs-parser@npm:7.0.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:3.10.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:6.6.0 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:7.1.1 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0013: │ yargs@npm:8.0.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 11.03s
➤ YN0000: ┌ Link step
➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A1.2.13#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=1.2.13&hash=87eb42 The platform linux is incompatible with this module, building skipped.
➤ YN0062: │ fsevents@patch:fsevents@npm%3A2.1.3#builtin<compat/fsevents>::version=2.1.3&hash=87eb42 The platform linux is incompatible with this module, building skipped.
➤ YN0007: │ core-js@npm:2.6.11 must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0007: │ uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@npm:0.4.6 [85052] must be built because it never did before or the last one failed
➤ YN0000: └ Completed in 7.76s
➤ YN0000: Done with warnings in 1.1m

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:
Error: Cannot find module '/home/nandini/Documents/courseraFSWD/React/confusion/node_modules/react-scripts/package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js
- /home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:964:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)
    at checkNodeVersion (/home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js:514:23)
    at /home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js:312:7
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js',
    '/home/nandini/.nvm/versions/node/v14.9.0/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js'
  ]
}

Deleting generated file... package.json
Done.
```

**versions of packages:**
node -v : v14.9.0
, npm -v : 6.14.8
, yarn --version : 2.2.2
, nvm --version : 0.35.1

And i am using a ubuntu version 20.04

Comment: Have you tried with --use-npm flag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to install CRA globally on your machine, these commands work perfectly fine:-

```
 yarn create react-app client
```

or

```
npx create-react-app client
```

**Happy hacking!**

Answer (score 1):

The following are steps to overcome this problem.

**Step 1:** Make sure that You've installed "create-react-app" after the update.

**Command:** npm install -g create-react-app //g for global installation

**Step 2:** Now Run this command to create your react app.

**Command:** npx/yarn create-react-app confusion

//Please check the version of create-react-app before executing below command

npx create-react-app confusion --scripts-version=react-scripts@1.1.4

Comment: Thnks a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of all yarn errors here: https://yarnpkg.com/advanced/error-codes

it seems that you have to run `yarn rebuild`, if it doesn't work also consider doing a clean build (cleaning cache and installing fresh)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to create a react app.

1. Globally (Permanently)
2. Locally (Not Permanently)

To create a react app globally, use the following command.

`npm install -g create-react-app`

Navigate to the directory where you want to place your application within. Then type the following command:

`create-react-app <name-of-app>`

If you already installed in your machine and a new version of create-react-app is released then you always need to uninstall the previous version and then reinstall it.

The command for uninstalling: `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`

If you don't want to install permanently then use `npm i create-react-app`.
Navigate to the placable directory and type the command for the new react app.

`npx create-react-app confusion` or
`yarn create-react-app confusion`

When new versions of Create React App are released, you can upgrade it by the following command:

`npm install react-scripts@latest`

For Ubuntu you can read the blog in  https://fosslovers.com/how-to-install-reactjs-on-ubuntu-20-04/
They have explained how to install react in Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your command line

```
npm cache clean --force
```

and then:

```
create-react-app basics
```

This one will help.